# setting up javadocs for achartengine

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc, achartengine

I'm using eclipse indigo and I want to import \ add the documentation for achartengine,
after downloading the zip file from : 
[javadocs link](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/detail?name=achartengine-1.1.0-javadocs.zip&can=2&q=)

i tried to add it to the jar file under the build path -> libraries -> engine 1.1.0 -> Edit the javadoc loation section -> insert Javadoc in archive.

then I tried to rebuild the project and did dome desperate staff.

I can't see the javadocs while hoovering over functions or hitting F2.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the javadocs, you need to import the sources. Once you checkout the sources, hit <kbd>F3</kbd> on a class in the AChartEngine packages and then "Attach sources..." and navigate to the source directory.